# vue change specific du/component router path

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

Hey there another question:

i have a div named group in the group i have several blocks/divs below the group

the group(parent) is here:

```
<div v-if="block.blocktype == 'partial'">
      <h1>{{block.name}}</h1>
      <component v-if="block.template_path" :is="block.template_path" :key="block.template_path" v-bind:bduuid="block.uuid"  v-bind:block_data="block.block_data">
      </component>
    </div>
```

div component like this:

```
<v-date-picker
        ref="picker"
        v-model="date"
        :picker-date.sync="pickerDate"
        :events="arrayEvents"
        event-color="green lighten-1"
        full-width
        reactive="true"
        :locale="this.localication"
      ></v-date-picker>
    </div>
<span style="color: blue;" @click="CreateNewAppintmentFunction()">Create new Appointment</span>
```

so now i want to change the child view from "show" to "new" after click 
with a `this.$router.push("appointment/quickedit");`the

```
CreateNewAppintmentFunction()
```

anyone a idea how i can change the router path from "show appointment" to "new appointment"

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I get correctly, but if you want to have dynamic path for page. You can do something like this

For example:

```
{ path: "baseurl/:appointment/quickedit", component: YourComponent, name: yourComponentName ... }
```

You can set your key word as router param.

```
this.$router.push("baseurl/show_appointmen/quickedit")
this.$router.push("baseurl/edit_appointmen/quickedit")
```

and in mounted hook you can get appointment param, and do your logic.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer but if i do so, it change the complete page but i only want to change the divs router from show to edit/new
because i have serveral component in a page and dont want so go to a other page when i only edit one div